# Customizing Matlab autocomplete: Can you exclude a specific function?

Tags: matlab, customization

I often fix my indentation by tabbing wildly, which led me to learn of the *enddrag* function.

Of course, this is not a function I expect to use a lot, and I would prefer not to have it pop up when I hit TAB on an *end*.  Is there any way to tell Matlab that  I don't want *enddrag* to appear in my tab completion list?

Comment: There is likely no way to customize this. Can you not just use smart indent (or select a block of text and tab the whole thing) and forgo all of the manual tabbing? I usually use Command-[ and Command-] (probably Ctrl-[ and Ctrl-] on Windows) to tab left and right which avoids the auto complete issue. Or just don't put your cursor at the end of a line when you tab.

Comment: It's definitely not a critical problem, more the principle of it.

Comment: I take it that this is mainly an issue for aligning comments, as the autoindent should deal with the actual code. I don't think this is part of matlab, but perhaps it can be made using something like the [Intelligent Code Completion File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25217-intelligent-code-completion-for-matlab) as inspiration.